# Sequelize BelongsToManyAddAssociationMixin performing update instead of insert in polymorphic table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having a problem within my application that is related to multiple tables/models arranged in a Many:Many relationship but also leverages polymorphic columns and is using the `BelongsToManyAddAssociationMixin`.  I am unable to insert multiple records in a M:N relationship because I'm unable to tell Sequelize to change the unique fields to include `roleableId`

Essentially I have a `User` model, a `Role` model, a relationship table called `UserRole` and other models which are "roleable" (For the sake of this example, one model is a `Facility`)

So essentially my `UserRole` model looks like

```
export class UserRole extends Model {
  public readonly id!: UUID
  public RoleId!: UUID
  public UserId!: UUID
  public roleableType!: string
  public roleableId!: string

  public readonly User!: User
  public readonly Role!: Role

  public getUser!: BelongsToGetAssociationMixin<User>
  public getRole!: BelongsToGetAssociationMixin<Role>
}

export const initializeUserRole = (sequelize: Sequelize) => {
  UserRole.init(
    {
      RoleId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          isUUID: 4,
        },
        field: 'role_id',
      },
      UserId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          isUUID: 4,
        },
        field: 'user_id',
      },
      roleableId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        field: 'roleable_id',
        validate: {
          isUUID: 4,
        },
      },
      roleableType: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'roleable_type',
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      sequelize,
      tableName: TableNames.USER_ROLES,
    }
  )
}
```

In my scenario, I would have a role named `Sales Rep` and it's primary key is a UUID

In theory, I would like to create a new record for the user to have the `SalesRep` role twice in my `UserRole` table, one with values for `roleableId` & `roleableType` and one where those values are null.

Using mixins, I'm able to add these roles with something like

```
const randomUser = await userFactory()
const salesRepRole = await roleFactory({ roleName: 'Sales Rep' })

await randomUser.addRole(salesRepRole)
```

^^^ This works properly

But if I try to do something like:

```
const randomUser = await userFactory()
const randomFacility = await facilityFactory()
const salesRepRole = await roleFactory({ roleName: 'Sales Rep' })

await randomUser.addRole(salesRepRole)
await randomuser.addRole(salesRepRole, { through: { roleableId: randomFacility.id, roleableType: 'facility' }})
```

What will happen is that instead of performing a new insert into my `UserRole` table, instead Sequelize will identify that there is already a record based upon `User.id` & `Role.id` and will perform an `UPDATE` instead, resulting in only one record being returned.

I'm not sure how to indicate to Sequelize that instead of putting a unique constraint on `User.id` & `Role.id`, I really need it to be `User.id`, `Role.id` & `roleableId`

My work around right now has been to simply just roll my own `add<Model>` function which will perform an INSERT properly (adding an index on my DB to check for unique instances of `user_id,role_id,roleable` that throw an error if this combination already exists) but this feels a bit dirty and I'd rather try to utilize the mixin as much as possible, especially if I also have to add a `BelongsToManyAddAssociationsMixin` version as well for `addRoles`

Does anyone have any ideas?  I'm happy to elaborate more if that helps.

Thanks!